# Lost of project

Tags: camera

I am trying to design a full 3D human body design. Today, I clicked on the camera button by curiousity but I think I lost the project. 
This is what I achieved so far and I think I lost it. 
[image]
I am new on blender and I really need your help this is what the project shows me when Iopen the saved project. 
[image]
Please how can I get my project back. Any Idea?

Thank you  in advance.

Answer (score 2):

On your current screen you have both the timeline and UV editor open. I assume you want the 3D viewer, so click on the bottom left button, with the icon of a little landscape. From here you can select editor you want, which is 3D view to get back to your model.

[image: The Editor Type dropdown menu]

You are clearly very new to blender. I'd recommend moving onto the new version 2.82 which is much clearer and a less cluttered interface.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It helps.